# How to find number of vowels in a list of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is to find the number of vowels in each word from list, and output the dictionary with the results.

I've tried this way:

```
wordsList = ["creativity", "anna", "civic", "apology", "refer", "mistress", "rotor", "mindset"]
dictionary = {}
vowels = "aeoui"
count = 0

for word in wordsList:
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            count = count + 1
            dictionary[word] = (count)

print(dictionary)
```

That's at which point i am, i need help how to count for each word specifically. Thanks in advance!
Expected output:

```
{anna:2} etc.
```

Comment: You need to reset count for each word, otherwise you include the number of vowels for all previous words. In addition, you should remove two levels of indentation on the line where you put the count into dictionary; and the parentheses there are meaningless and should be removed as well.

Comment: Yea, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that count needs to be initializes inside the loop:
you also can add a part where you count both upper case and lower case vowels.

```
wordsList = ["creativity", "anna", "civic", "apology", "refer", "mistress", "rotor", "mindset"]
dictionary = {}
vowels = "aeoui"

for word in wordsList:
    count = 0 # I moved it
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in vowels: # to consider both upper/lower case
            count = count + 1
            dictionary[word] = (count)

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Oh yea! Thanks so much! Very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression with a test of vowel for each letter in a word in the `sum` function:

```
dictionary = {word: sum(letter in 'aeiou' for letter in word) for word in wordsList}
```

`dictionary` becomes:

```
{'creativity': 4, 'anna': 2, 'civic': 2, 'apology': 3, 'refer': 2, 'mistress': 2, 'rotor': 2, 'mindset': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that in such a way, very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You were not resetting count variable to 0 at the start of checking next word. I also fixed the indentation of `dictionary[word] = count`

```
wordsList = ["creativity", "anna", "civic", "apology", "refer", "mistress", "rotor", "mindset"]
dictionary = {}
vowels = "aeoui"
count = 0

for word in wordsList:
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            count = count + 1
    dictionary[word] = count

print(dictionary)
#{'creativity': 4, 'anna': 2, 'civic': 2, 'apology': 3, 'refer': 2, 'mistress': 2, 'rotor': 2, 'mindset': 2}
```

Comment: Yea, forgot to reset the loop! Thanks so much, very appreciated!

Comment: Great. Please upvote/accept if the answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

Often things like this are done using comprehensions in Python. The following is more idiomatic Python than using for loops and counter variables, and breaks down the steps for you. (It also deals with capital letters by converting the word to lowercase before testing it.)

```
words = ['creativity', 'SpongbUngulator']

vowel_counts = {}
vowels = set('aeiou')
for word in words:
    lowercase_word = word.lower()
    found_vowels = [letter for letter in lowercase_word if letter in vowels]
    vowel_count = len(found_vowels)
    vowel_counts[word] = vowel_count
print(vowel_counts)
```

It's worth pointing out that `set(lowercase_word).intersection(vowels)` will tell you which *unique* vowels are in each word. Python sets are well worth getting to know.